# Calculadora em Python

Tags: python

Fiz uma calculadora em Python como exercício prático, não usei funções nem pesquisei nada, apenas fiz o que sei. gostaria de saber se o código está bom, mesmo sem a utilização de funções(após irei utilizar também para praticar :D). se puderem dar esse auxilio de dizer se está um código limpo, bem comentado e fácil de entender. Estou aprendendo ainda e gostaria de saber se estou no caminho certo. agradeço muito desde já!

```
# Calculadora 1.0

# importa a função sleep() para criar pausas
from time import sleep as sl


# Da start no programa - OK
while True:
    while True:
        try:
            rodar = int(input("Deseja iniciar o programa? [1- sim  2- não] : "))
            break
        except:
            print("Erro: Você deve digitar um número")
            sl(2)
            continue

    # caso sim - OK
    if rodar == 1:
        Roda = True
        break
        sl(2)

    # caso não - OK
    elif rodar == 2:
        print("\nBeleza então!")
        Roda = False
        break
        sl(2)
    
    # verifica erro - OK
    elif rodar != 1 or rodar != 2:
        print("Erro: Opção inválida, tente novamente!")
        sl(2)
        continue

# Loop principal - OK
while Roda:
    # Entrada de dados - OK
    while True:
        try:
            pn = float(input("Primeiro número: "))
            sn = float(input("Segundo  número: "))
            break
        except:
            print("Erro: você deve digitar um número!")
            sl(2)
            continue

    # Loop de operções com os números passados - OK
    sim = True
    while sim:
        # testa se o usuario inseriu mesmo um número - OK
        while True:
            try:
                print("""
                Qual operração matemática você gostaria de realizar?
                1- soma
                2- subtração
                3- divisão
                4- multiplicação

                5- sair
                """)
                opc = int(input(">: "))
                break
            except:
                print("Erro: valor inválido tente novamente!")
                sl(2)
                continue

        # Saída de dados/Programa - OK
        # soma - OK
        if opc == 1:
            soma = pn + sn
            print(f"\n{pn} + {sn} = {soma}")
            
        # subtração - OK
        elif opc == 2:
            sub = pn - sn
            print(f"\n{pn} - {sn} = {sub}")

        # divisão - OK
        elif opc == 3:
            div = pn / sn
            print(f"\n{pn} / {sn} = {div}")

        # multiplicação - OK
        elif opc == 4:
            mult = pn * sn
            print(f"\n{pn} x {sn} = {mult}")

        # sair do programa - OK
        elif opc == 5:
            print("Até a próxima!")
            exit()

        # Erro - OK
        else:
            print("Erro: Você deve escolher uma das opções disponíveis!")
            sl(2)
            continue
        
        # verifica se o usuario ainda vai usar os mesmos números - OK
        while True:
            while True:
                try:
                    esc = int(input("Deseja realizar mais alguma operação com estes números [1- sim  2- não] : "))
                    break
                except:
                    print("Erro: escolha apenas entre as duas opções!")
                    sl(2)
                    continue

            # caso sim - OK
            if esc == 1:
                sim = True
                break
                sl(2)

            # caso não - OK
            elif esc == 2:
                print("\nBeleza então!")
                sim = False
                break
                sl(2)
            
            # verifica erro - OK
            elif esc != 1 or esc != 2:
                print("Erro: Opção inválida, tente novamente!")
                continue
        
        # Testa se o usuario ainda quer usar o programa
        while True:
            while True:           
                try:
                    rodar = int(input("\nDeseja continuar no programa? [1- sim  2- não] : "))
                    break
                except:
                    print("Erro: Você deve digitar um número!")
                    sl(2)
                    continue

            # caso sim - OK
            if rodar == 1:
                Roda = True
                break
                sl(2)

            # caso não - OK
            elif rodar == 2:
                print("\nAté a próxima!")
                Roda = False
                break
                sl(2)
            
            # verifica erro - OK
            elif rodar != 1 or rodar != 2:
                print("Erro: Opção inválida, tente novamente!")
                continue
```

Comment: esqueci de mencionar que fiz tudo no Google Colab, por isso não coloquei nenhum código que limpe o terminal. Lá não tem como :(

Comment: Livro: Clean Code. Seu codigo não ta legal não bro. Podia ter uns metodos ai para evitar codigo repedito, entre outras coisas.

Comment: A parte dos métodos eu citei na pergunta, fiz sem usar as funções só como teste prático.

Answer (score 1):

## A seguir algumas coisas que atrapalham na compreensão do código.

- Você nomeou o *sleep* da biblioteca *time* como *sl*, mas acho que seria bom não nomeá-lo, porque ficará melhor para a compreensão, principalmente em códigos maiores.
- Alguns comentários têm que melhorar. Como o "caso sim". O que "caso sim"? E o "caso não". Caso não o quê? Seria melhor que fossem algo como "caso queira iniciar o programa" e "senão".
- Melhore os nomes das variáveis, e tente não fazer coisas como "rodar" e "Roda" para nomear as variáveis. Os nomes de variáveis devem por convenção estar em letras minúsculas, e é bom que você deixe claro o que elas são. Um exemplo:

```
while True:
    try:
        n1 = float(input("Entre um número: "))
        n2 = float(input("Entre outro número: "))
        
        soma = n1 + n2
        break
        
    except ValueError:
        print("\nVocê precisa digitar um número!\n")
    
print(soma)
```

- Se puder, diminua os *while*. Tente deixar os *while True* claros ou tente mudar para coisas como *while estiver_rodando* ou *while not acabou*.
- Existem alguns *sleep* que não estão funcionando porque estão vindo depois de um *break*, ou seja, estão sendo ignorados.

Estas são algumas coisas que atrapalham a compreensão do código. Minha dica é que agora que você tem uma visão de como o programa funciona, reescreva-o do zero consultando este. Sempre me ajuda.